# selecting from multiple tables with counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one holds a category with column catID,catName and the other has the catID as a foreign key, now i want to select all the  total items on the second table based on their catID.
E.g. What is the total number of individual element if their category is 1,2,3,4 etc. Pls code hints will help thanks.

Comment: This is a simple group by. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Daniel, never knew how to go about it, can you gimme tips?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   c.cat_id
   ,count(*) as occurence
FROM category c
INNER JOIN table2 t ON (c.cat_id = t.cat_id)
GROUP BY c.cat_id
```

If you want the categories with occurence = 0 then do:

```
SELECT
   c.cat_id
   ,count(t.cat_id) as occurence
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN table2 t ON (c.cat_id = t.cat_id)
GROUP BY c.cat_id
```

**Links:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlgroupby.html

Comment: No need for the join, you can directly execute the select on table2, except if you also want occurence = 0 for entries in category without entries in table2. But your statement doesn't support that either.

Comment: Daniel yes i also want occurance 0, what Johan did was gd, nice heads up, but can I see yours too.

Comment: Thanks Jonah, you are far too kind.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT catName, COUNT(table2.catId) FROM table1,table2   
    WHERE table1.catId=table2.catId  
GROUP BY catName
```

Comment: -1 for using implicit `where`join syntax. It's bad, confusing, error prone and it throws the optimizer off on complex joins. Use explicit joins instead.

Comment: Thanks Lvil, but couldn't get for occurance 0.